# Why does a function parameter call a constructor with an argument?

Tags: c++

I have this code(stolen from cplusplus.com):

```
// explicit:
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class A {};

class B {
public:
  explicit B (const A& x) {}
  B& operator= (const A& x) {return *this;}
  operator A() {return A();}
};

void fn (B x) {}

int main ()
{
  A foo;
  B bar (foo);
  bar = foo;
  foo = bar;

//  fn (foo);  // not allowed for explicit ctor.
  fn (bar);  

  return 0;
}
```

So apparently the statement `fn (foo);` would call the constructor defined in class B, and I do not really get why. Why would that call a constructor with an argument, I mean aren't things simply copied to the function parameters when not using a reference? If `fn (foo);` calls the constructor `B (const A& x) {}`, shouldn't `fn (bar);` generate an error since there is no constructor defined for an argument of type B, such as `B (const B& x) {}`?

Comment: _I mean aren't things simply copied to the function parameters when not using a reference?_ For complex types, such as `class`es - copy constructors are invoked, since, _simply copying_, might break data integrity.

Comment: My knowledge of C++ caught some dust; Would `fn (bar);` use a copy constructor to copy `bar`?

Comment: Of course! I forgot about copy constructors.. Thanks guys

Answer (score 2):

It's all because of `fn()`'s signature:

```
void fn (B x) {}
```

fn only accepts objects of type B, and passes them by value.
So what happens when calling fn() with an object of type A?

```
 A foo;
 fn (foo);  // not allowed for explicit ctor.
```

The compiler tries to find the best matching function - a function called fn and receives type A.  ([Overload resolution](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/overload_resolution))
Because there is no such function, it then tries to find the next best match by casting the object to a type that fn() accepts.
A conversion constructor would usually do the job :   `B (const A& x) {}`
But because it's marked with an [explicit](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/explicit) specifier the compiler can't do it implicitly.

You would have to explicitly cast the object for the compiler to find a match:

```
fn ((B)foo);  // Explicit conversion is allowed.
```

Comment: Thanks, but I do not get the last line. Are you calling the conversion constructor explicitly so that it all works out? If so, why is there a comment afterwards saying that it is not allowed, or did you just forget to remove it?

Comment: @Bobby - It's a copy-paste error. I've fixed the comment.

Answer (score 0):

That is a result of an explicit creation of an object

```
fn(foo);
```

is not implicitly possible since `fn()` doesn't takes any A object as parameter

BUT your ***foo*** parameter can actually be used to create an instance of ***B*** which match perfectly the ***fn*** parameter, you can prevent that implicitly conversion of objects using the ***explicit*** keyword.

And that is what you are doing here:

```
 explicit B (const A& x) {}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well ... `B(const B&)` although not explicitly declared, is there.  That's because it is one of the special functions for which the compiler has a default:

```
B()
B(const B&)
B(B&&)
B& operator=(const B&)
B& operator==(B&&)
~B()
```

So, B can copy itself.
It cannot convert implicitly form A being such a conversion is declared as explicit.

`fn(B(foo))` would have worked.

Answer (score 0):

From the C++ Standard

15 **The initialization that occurs in the = form** of a brace-or-equal-initializer or condition (6.4), as well **as in argument passing**, function return, throwing an exception (15.1), handling an exception (15.3), and aggregate member initialization (8.6.1), **is called copy-initialization**. [ Note: Copy-nitialization may invoke a move (12.8).—end note ]

Thus for the explicit constructor

```
explicit B (const A& x) {}
```

this initialization that in fact is used for the initialization of the function parameter

```
A foo;
B bar = foo;
```

is wrong.

It is the direct initialization that can be used with the explicit constructor as it is shown in your program

```
A foo;
B bar( foo );
```

Comment: By quoting the standard, did you refer to the copy-constructor or? And one more: If `fn(foo)` is not allowed, why is `B bar (foo)`? Is there anything explicit about `B bar (foo)`? Thanks again

Comment: @Bobby See your constructor declaration explicit B (const A& x) {}. This constructor should be called in the case of the copy initialization. However it is an explicit constructor. So the compiler issues an error.